# Speed-up inverse of weighted least squares covariance matrix in R

Tags: r, performance, matrix

I need to speed up the calculation of the inverse of a WLS covariance matrix in R, where the matrix, `wls.cov.matrix`, is given by (full example below):

```
n = 10000
X = matrix(c(rnorm(n,1,2), sample(c(1,-1), n, replace = TRUE), rnorm(n,2,0.5)), nrow = 1000, ncol = 3)
Q = diag(rnorm(n, 1.5, 0.3))
wls.cov.matrix = solve(t(X)%*%diag(1/diag(Q))%*%X)
```

Is it possible to speed up this calculation?

MORE INFO VERY RELEVANT TO THE FINAL GOAL:
This is still little information, let me explain more my goal and will be clearer if there are ways to speed up my code.
I run 1,0000s of times wls.cov.matrix so I need it to be much faster.

However, each time I run it I use the same X, the only matrix that changes is Q, which is a diagonal matrix.

If `X` was a square matrix, of same dim as `Q`, I could just precompute `X^-1` and `(X^T)^(-1)`,

```
X.inv = solve(X)
X.inv.trans = solve(t(X))
```

and then for each iteration run:

```
Q.inv = diag(1/diag(Q))
wls.cov.matrix = X.inv%*%Q.inv%*%X.inv.trans
```

But my `X` is not square, so is there any other trick?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main time-consuming part here is `t(X)%*%diag(1/diag(Q))%*%X`, not the calculation of its inverse.

A nice trick is to calculate it as

```
crossprod(X / sqrt(diag(Q)));
```

Confirmation:

```
all.equal( (t(X) %*% diag(1/diag(Q)) %*% X) , crossprod(X / sqrt(diag(Q))) );

[1] TRUE
```

To compare the timing run:

```
Qdiag = diag(Q);
system.time({(t(X) %*% diag(1/Qdiag) %*% X)})
system.time({crossprod(X / sqrt(Qdiag))})
```

Comment: you are the mind master of Linear Algebra! Thanks so so much!

Comment: another short Q, what about a trick for computing the mean estimate of the WLS, i.e., (X^{T}Q^{-1}X)^{-1}X^{T}Q^{-1}y... if you have an answer for that as well please let me know - I also put it as an SO question so other people can benefit: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24207457/speed-up-inverse-calculation-of-weighted-least-squares-mean-estimate-in-r

Comment: The main gain in the performance would be achieved by not having any n-by-n matrices along the way. I mean not having the Q matrix, only working with its diagonal.

Comment: Ok, I've added an answer there.

Answer (score 2):

Well, `Q` is a diagonal matrix, so its inverse is just given by the inverses of the diagonal entries. You can thus do

```
X = matrix(c(rnorm(n,1,2), sample(c(1,-1), n, replace = TRUE), rnorm(n,2,0.5)), nrow = 1000, ncol = 3)
Qinv = diag(1/rnorm(n, 1.5, 0.3))
wls.cov.matrix = solve(t(X)%*%Qinv%*%X)
```

And in fact, this speeds things up by about a factor of 20.

Comment: Hi Hong Ooi,  thanks a lot! I already had that in my actual code, I was looking to speed up the solve of with Q.inv done that way.... sorry for the mistypo in the question